# Using Jquery Hide&Show for multiple elements on the same page

Tags: jquery

Hi I am trying to create a page that uses the Hide and show functions multiple times to hide differernt pieces of text. I followed a tutorial on w3schools and edited the code to try and make it work. However I am getting and error whereby the hide and show function only works on the first piece of text and not the others.
here is my code

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/javascript/jquery-1.6.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#hide").click(function(){
    $("p").hide();
  });
 $("#show").click(function(){
    $("p").show();
  });
});
</script>
<div class="questions" id="question-1">
    <h1>Question</h1>
</div>
<p>
    answer</p>
<div id="hide">
    Hide</div>
<div id="show">
    Show</div>
<div class="questions" id="question-2">

        <h1>Question</h1>
</div>
<p>
    Answer</p>
<div id="hide">
    Hide</div>
<div id="show">
    Show</div>
```

Does anyone know as to why this may be happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

because you are using id's instead of classes. id's are allowed to exist once in a html page.

Ok, for your comment, you can relate them with an attribute like this :

```
<p rel='answer_1'>Answer</p>
<div class="hide" answer='1'>Hide</div>
<div class="show" answer='1'>Show</div>
```

and then in your script :

```
$(".hide").click(function(){
    $("p[rel='answer_" + $(this).attr("answer") + "']").hide();
});

$(".show").click(function(){
    $("p[rel='answer_" + $(this).attr("answer") + "']").show();
});
```

Comment: Hi thanks for your reply that really helped. I have another issue. The hide and show functions work for each question but when you click hide or show it hides every answer. I want to be able to just hide answers individually.

Comment: Hi thanks again for your reply. I tested this code on my site and it doesnt seem to work when anything is clicked on

Comment: Thanks for your help its all sorted now

Answer (score 0):

Do not ever use the same `ID` for multiple elements. I've changed your code by an increment or two to create something that should work. I've introduced a `data` attribute to the show/hide links, the value of which is shared by the relevant answer. Now you can get the value of the `data-id` attribute when show or hide are clicked and then generate your jQuery selector from the value. There's a lot more you could do to DRY this up, but it's a working first step in the right direction.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/javascript/jquery-1.6.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".hide").click(function(){
    var id = $(this).attr('data-id');
    $("p." + id).hide();
  });
 $(".show").click(function(){
    var id = $(this).attr('data-id');
    $("p." + id).show();
  });
});
</script>

<div class="questions" id="question-1">
 <h1>Question</h1>
</div>

<p data-id='answer-a'>answer</p>
<div class="hide" data-id='answer-a'>Hide</div>
<div class="show" data-id='answer-a'>Show</div>
```